# how to create a link only if a link doesn't already exist in netlogo

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm a Netlogo neophyte learning by doing, and hoping someone can help me solve what appears as a simple enough operation:

At each tick, and for each turtle X, I want to create or strengthen an undirected link to each other turtle Y lying within radius **radius**, with a certain probability **createlinkprob**. If a link *already* exists between X and Y I want to increment the multiplicity of that link. (Since Netlogo allows only one link to exist, I need to store the multiplicity in a link variable as a way to indicate a stronger link.)  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

The following code illustrates roughly what I want, but doesn't work. (In the inner "ask" of **to generate-event**
to all turtles within the radius my understanding is that "myself" refers to the calling turtle X, while "self" refers to Y. That part appears to work. I'm trying to identify the link using **who** numbers but that part doesn't.)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
links-own
[
  multiplicity
]


to setup
  clear-all
  make-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to make-turtles
  create-turtles num-nodes [ set size 3 ]
  ;; layout-circle turtles max-pxcor - 1
  ask turtles [
  ;; move each turtle to a random point
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
]
end


to go
  generate-event
  ask turtles
  [
   fd random 2
   rt -5 + random 10
  ]
  ask links
  [
    if random 100 < removelinkprob 
    [ifelse multiplicity = 1 [die] [set multiplicity multiplicity - 1]]
  ]
  tick
end


to generate-event 
  ;; at every event - one per tick - each turtle may connect to others in radius R with probability createlinkprob/100. 
  ;; If already connected, the multiplicity value is incremented.
  ;; Otherwise, the multiplicity value is set to 1 and a link is created.
  ask turtles
  [
  ask other turtles in-radius radius
    [if random 100 < createlinkprob [
      ifelse in-link-neighbor? myself 
      [
        ask link who (show [who] of myself) set multiplicity (multiplicity + 1)
      ]
      [create-link-with myself [set multiplicity 1]]]
    ]
  ]
end


; based on  http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/GiantComponent
; Copyright 2005 Uri Wilensky.
; Modified by Michael Frishkopf
; under Creative Commons license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/
```

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Those who want to help you need to be able to copy&paste into NetLogo the code you provided and have a functioning example to work with; instead of having to create code themselves around the example you provided not to answer the question, but only to start working on it.

Comment: thanks; I've provided what I think is a minimal example, though it won't run for the reasons cited.

Answer (score 2):

Following the edit where you provided a working example...

The structure of your code is already fit for doing what you want it to do.
The only reason why it does not work is because of two syntax problems.

1. `link` requires two reporters, i.e. the two turtles at the ends of the link ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#link)). You wrote `link who (show [who] of myself)`. While `who` is a reporter reporting a turtle, `show [who] of myself` is not a reporter: `show` prints a value, so you have to remove `show` and just write `link (who) ([who] of myself)` (note that the round brackets here are optional, and that their setup simply is a stylistic choice for readability).
2. `ask` requires square brackets enclosing the command ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ask)), therefore you have to put square brackets around `set multiplicity (multiplicity + 1)`.

---

This leads to a reflection on the question itself.
When you write in NetLogo the code you provided, NetLogo brings you very precisely to where the problem is: it highlights the world `show` and it gives you the following error message

> Expected reporter

You should have been aware of this, and should have tailored your question to address this problem you had; or, perhaps better given the foundational nature of the problem, looked up what reporters are in NetLogo - [see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#procedures) the Programming Guide.
The same goes with `ask`: after you fix the first syntax problem, NetLogo brings you very directly to where the second problem is, it highlights `ask` and it gives you the following error message

> ASK expected 2 inputs, an agent or agentset and a command block

So it would have been particularly easy to check how `ask` works and see that it requires the command block to be in square brackets.

Note that this is exactly what you should do to [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see in particular the sections *Minimal* and *Reproducible - Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem*); with the additional benefit that, by following this guidance, you would have almost certainly resolved the two syntax problems yourself.

So please, in the future make sure that you check what error messages you are receiving and that you ask a question which is pertinent to those errors and following the website's guidance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation, and apologies for the naivety of the question ...I tried to follow the "expected reporter" lead but was confused about reporters, syntax, and scoping. I'll surely do more homework before asking next time. Again, thank you!